# Check whether the schedule overlaps each other?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logic

I need to find whether a new event created over laps any of the existing event.

Event Table

```
ID EventName StartTime EndTime 
1  Event1    11:30AM   12PM    
2  Event2    11:30AM   11:40AM 
3  Event3    11:40AM   12PM    
4  Event4    12PM      12:30PM 
5  Event5    11:30AM   12:30PM
```

In above table, event 2 overlaps event 1, event 3 overlaps event 1, event 5 overlaps event 1...

Current event start time and existing schedule end time, current end time and existing schedule start time can be same.

I am trying to compare the whether the new event event time overlaps existing event time using the following logic but it fails

```
if (currentStartTime == schedule.StartTime)
{
count++;
continue;
}
else if (currentStartTime == schedule.EndTime)
{
continue;
}
else if (currentEndTime == schedule.StartTime)
{
continue;
}
else if (currentStartTime > schedule.StartTime && currentStartTime < schedule.EndTime     && currentEndTime >= schedule.EndTime)
{
count++;
continue;
}
else if (currentEndTime <= schedule.EndTime && currentEndTime > schedule.StartTime &&     currentStartTime < schedule.StartTime)
{
count++;
continue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably simpler to invert the problem and ask "when do two intervals *not* overlap?" Answer: when the end of interval A is <= the start of interval B, or when the end of interval B is <= the start of interval A. Create an expression for this, and negate it.

Comment: It check whether the second date range falls completely inside the first date range, but my requirement is different consider 10-12 and 9-11, here it should say it overlaps as 11 is between 10 and 12

Comment: @Sri Kumar: Read my answer again - I'm comparing the _end_ of interval A to the _start_ of interval B and the other way around; this will determine whether the intervals are completely outside of each other. If they are not completely outside of each other, then they overlap.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the [following article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx) useful and especially the `TimePeriodIntersector` class.