# Check whether the schedule overlaps between days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to find whether a new schedule overlaps any existing schedules.

This is the "intervals" table:

```
     id  first              last    
     1   1900-01-01 09:00   1900-01-01 10:00
     2   1900-01-01 15:00   1900-01-01 18:00
     3   1900-01-01 18:01   1900-01-01 08:00
```

I am using a scalar function **dbo.TimeOnly** for extracting time part from the datetime fields.

My selection criteria as follows

**First case**

```
     declare @start datetime
     declare @end datetime

     set @start = dbo.TimeOnly('2011-may-11 08:01:00');
     set @end = dbo.TimeOnly('2011-may-11 15:30:00');

     select  * from intervals where 
     ( NOT ( dbo.TimeOnly(last) < @start OR  @end < dbo.TimeOnly(first) ) )
```

This will return 1st and 2nd records. I got this logic from [Check whether the schedule overlaps each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565564/check-whether-the-schedule-overlaps-each-other)

**Second case**

```
    set @start = dbo.TimeOnly('2011-may-11 07:01:00');
    set @end = dbo.TimeOnly('2011-may-11 08:30:00');
```

How do I write a query that will return only the 3rd record for the criteria in the second case?

## **UPDATE**

I will give more details for my problem

Different people are managing a particular event for a certain time duration in a day.

For **Monday**, the schedule format is like this

```
    Id  Start       End          User   Days    
     1  00:01 AM    08:00 AM     'A'    1
     2  08:01 AM    04:00 PM     'B'    1
     3  04:00 PM    00:00 AM     'C'    1
```

For **Tuesday's**

```
     4  08:01 AM    04:00 PM     'B'    2
     5  07:00 PM    07:00 AM     'C'    2
```

For **Wednesday's**

```
     6  08:01 AM    04:00 PM     'A'    4
     7  10:00 PM    08:00 AM     'B'    4
```

Here days are stored in the bit value format ie

Monday=1,Tuesday=2,Wednesday=4,Thursday=8,Friday=16,Saturday=32 and Sunday=64

When we creating a schedule for a particular day, it should not overlap between times.
I would like to get a SQL query for checking any schedules exists while creating a new schedule for a particular day.

For a particular event time (*Say An even occured at 04:00 AM on Tuesday*) I would like to find the correct schedule (Will be "5") that falls between the Start and End time.

Comment: Anoop, for record 3 in your intervals table, is the `last` time 08:00 on the following day?  So should it be `1900-01-02 08:00` (essentially)?  And then would your **second case** scenario be `set @end = dbo.TimeOnly('2011-may-12 08:30:00');`

Comment: @Kit But I am checking the time part only for the second condition So this function returns `set @end = dbo.TimeOnly('2011-may-12 08:30:00');` `1900-01-01 08:30:00`

Comment: I understand that you are returning only the time, but the time periods you have listed in your second case won't overlap record 3 unless your end time is on May 12th instead of May 11th, you see.

Comment: Yes I understand. So how i can get the overlapping records that exists between days using SQL ?

Comment: Have a look at this question. I think it is what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002689/how-can-i-determine-in-sql-server-if-a-datetime-range-overlaps-another

Comment: @Mikael, that solution will work great if Anoop uses the whole date instead of just the time.

Comment: I don't see how 4AM on Tuesday falls within the #5 timespan.  Is that a typo?

Comment: @Kit Here Start is 07:00 PM and end is 07:00 AM on the next day. So 4AM  engulf the interval.

Comment: So then you meant 4AM on Wednesday.  I think to do this, you should figure each schedule and event relative to the hours in a week and then test which interval your event falls within.  This is a different question than your original question, though, so you might want to post it separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your SELECT to this:

```
select  * from intervals where 
(
( dbo.TimeOnly(last) > dbo.TimeOnly(first)
AND
NOT (dbo.TimeOnly(last) < @start OR  @end < dbo.TimeOnly(first)) )

OR

( dbo.TimeOnly(last) < dbo.TimeOnly(first)
AND
( @start >= dbo.TimeOnly(first) OR @end <= dbo.TimeOnly(last) OR (@start < dbo.TimeOnly(first) AND @end > dbo.TimeOnly(last)) ) )
)
```

I might've missed a parenthesis somewhere, but I hope not.

The concept here is a query with 2 main groupings combined with an OR.  The first clause checks intervals where *last > first* and is mainly a copy of your existing query with the addition of the *last > first* condition, while the 2nd clause checks intervals where *last < first*.

In the case where last < first, there are 3 ways that an interval can overlap:

- start is after the interval's first
- end is before the interval's last
- start and end completely engulf the interval, i.e., start is before first and end is after last

Any one of these 3 conditions would mean the schedule to check is within an existing interval, so the 3 conditions are combined with ORs.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something like this:

```
Declare @start datetime
Declare @duration int

Set @start = dbo.TimeOnly('2011-May-11 07:01:00');
-- Get the number of minutes in your timespan
Set @duration = DateDiff(minute, '2011-May-11 07:01:00', '2011-May-12 08:30:00');

Select id, first, last
From intervals
Where (DateDiff(minute, dbo.TimeOnly(first)), @start) + @duration) > 0
AND DateDiff(minute, dbo.TimeOnly(first), @start) <
 DateDiff(minute, dbo.TimeOnly(first), dbo.TimeOnly(last));
```

Assuming that your `dbo.TimeOnly` function is essentially the same as `Convert(time, {timefield})`.

This will first find the difference between the new start time and the existing start times, then will find out if the duration of the new period is longer than that difference.  This covers new periods that begin before or during existing ones.

The last clause compares the difference between the new start time and the existing start time to the duration of the existing period, to check whether the existing period is longer than the difference between them.  Otherwise, the new start time will naturally be after the existing end time, which means it does not overlap.